# Wireshark Dissector in Lua error: "Tree item ProtoField/Protocol handle is invalid"

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm new to Lua altogether, and this is my first attempt at writing a wireshark dissector.
I want to analyze SSH without cipher by Lua script. I write a script to detect the packet length and padding length for the first step.

Here is my script:

```lua
do
    local p_test = Proto("test","Test.");

    local f_packet_length = ProtoField.uint32("packet_length")
    local f_padding_length = ProtoField.uint8("padding_length")


    p_test.fields = {
        f_packet_length,
        f_padding_length
    }

    function p_test.dissector(buf,pkt,root)
        local offset = 0
        local buf_len = buf:len()

        local t = root:add(p_test, buf:range(offset))

        t:add(f_packet_length,buf:range(offset,4))
        offset = offset+4
        t:add(f_padding_length,buf:range(offset,1))
        offset = offset+1

    end

    local tcp_table = DissectorTable.get("tcp.port")

    tcp_table:add(22,p_test)
end
```

After I run the code through Evalutate Lua and applied the test filter, I find that there is an error in Packet Details:

```
Lua Error: [string "do..."]:19: Tree item ProtoField/Protocol handle is invalid (ProtoField/Proto not registered?)
```

Line 19 corresponds the `t:add(f_packet_length...` line.

Could anyone help to explain this error?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Your code above will work fine if it's in a real Lua script for Wireshark... either by being in a `.lua` file in the personal plugins directory, or by being loaded with the "`-X lua_script:<filename>`" command line switch.

But you can't register a new protocol in the `tools->evaluate` window, because it's too late by then to register a new protocol (or new fields).  Unfortunately the error Wireshark reports isn't clear about that, because it sort of half works, but really it's not working and cannot work.

The problem is new protocol registration happens in two phases internally: the first phase is when the Lua scripts are loaded and executed, which adds the protocol and fields to an internal temporary table, and then after all the lua scripts load then the second phase has new protocols and fields moved from the temporary table into their final run-time tables and registered, and then wireshark finishes loading and you see the GUI.  That second phase happens once and only once, when Wireshark first starts up.  But running the `tools->evaluate` window happens after all that, so it's too late.